# How could I compute the number from the database and show it to the Label everytime I change the combo box value?

Tags: c#

I have a database values that I have to show to the label as the person salay per hour.
My code is here:

```
sqc = con.CreateCommand();
string query5 = "SELECT [SalaryGrade] FROM tbl_gradestep where GradeNumber =" + cmbGradeNumber.SelectedItem.ToString() + " and StepNumber =" + cmbStepNumber.SelectedItem.ToString() + "";
sqc.CommandText = query5;

sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqc);
dt = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    lblSalary.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString();
    lblHour.Text = (dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString()/22/8);
}

con.Close();
```

The computation is database values divided by 22 then divide it again by 8.

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong - you can't use the `/` operator on a `string` and an `int`.  Parse the string to a number first.

Comment: How do you divide a string by a number?

Comment: What are the two `*` symbols doing in your `lblHour.Text` assignment?

Comment: can you please do the code? >.<

Comment: the * is the italic hehe

Comment: why two times ? dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString()?

Comment: lblHour.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"])/22/8).ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, quite explicitly, a string:

```
dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString()
```

A string is just text.  You don't perform math on it.  If this string is *guaranteed* to be an integer, you can convert it directly:

```
lblHour.Text = (int.Parse(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"])/22/8);
```

If it's not *guaranteed*, then you might want some error checking first:

```
int salaryGrade;
if (!int.TryParse(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"], out salaryGrade))
{
    // wasn't an integer, handle the error condition here
}
lblHour.Text = (salaryGrade/22/8);
```

**Note:** Integer division is going to result only in an integer.  If you're looking for decimal values, you're going to want to convert your numbers to something with decimal precision.  (Such as `decimal`, which also has `.Parse()` and `.TryParse()` methods of course.)  Otherwise you may just end up with zeroes and not know why.

Comment: uhm what if i want to put two decimal places?

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue: Use decimal instead of int for decimal precision.

Answer (score 0):

> the error is "Operator "/" cannot be applied to operands of type
>   "string" and "int"

The error message is pretty informative. The following

```
dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString()
```

is a `string` and `22` is an `int` literal. You can't apply the division operator to them. How could you divide a `string` with an `int`, it is a meaningless operation. That you need is something like the following:

```
((decimal)dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"])/(22*8)
```

First you cast the `SalaryGrade` to a decimal and then you divide this with the hours.

**Note**: In the above line I have assumed that `SalaryGrade` can be casted to a `decimal`. If the cast is not possible an exception would be thrown. So a more safe approach it would be to try to use the `TryParse` method of `decimal`:

```
decimal salaryGrade;
if(decimal.TryParse(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"], out salaryGrade))
{
    var salaryPerHour = salaryGrade/(22*8);
}
```

Comment: specified cast is not valid :(

Comment: @James-DeanLorenzoAlimboyogue what's the datatype of `SalaryGrade` in the database?

Comment: varchar(50)

it gives me the output 
"xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
how can i make it just two numbers after the point? hehe

Comment: nah im fine now i just put "0.00" to the .ToString("0.00")

Comment: excuse me sir, can you voted up my question? :( i can't ask a question anymore :((

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you cannot use a math operation in a string!
Try this: declare an int variable and assign to it the data from the table and then use the int in the "label.Text" assign converting that int to string.
Hope helped ya!

Comment: You are right here. Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for helping me out here. I read all your answers then modify my code and boom. Works like a charm.

```
 decimal salaryGrade;  
  sqc = con.CreateCommand();
        string query5 = "SELECT [SalaryGrade] FROM tbl_gradestep where GradeNumber =" + cmbGradeNumber.SelectedItem.ToString() + " and StepNumber =" + cmbStepNumber.SelectedItem.ToString() + "";
        sqc.CommandText = query5;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqc);
        dt = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblSalary.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString();                     
            if (decimal.TryParse(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SalaryGrade"].ToString(), out salaryGrade))
            {
              
            }
           lblHour.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(salaryGrade / 22 / 8).ToString("0.00");              
        }            
        con.Close();
    }
```